# How to split one column into multiple with uneven delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataset of school, city, state. All of them separated by commas. I'm trying to separate them into three new columns for analysis. each new column named school, city, state.

[The original dataset. They won't let me put pictures in here yet so here's a link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IXtF.png)

The problem I'm running into is that the commas are used sometimes in the school name and that throws things off and forces the creation of a new column and just generally doesn't work.

This is the code I used to split the column:

```
undergrad_colleges_supplying_50_med_students_test = undergrad_colleges_supplying_50_med_students.join(undergrad_colleges_supplying_50_med_students['undergraduate_institution'].str.split(',', expand=True).fillna(np.nan))
```

This is what that outputs. It gives me multiple new columns I'm not sure why and it also is separating by the comma present in some of the school names.

[Processed Dataframe image. There should only be three columns but I ended up with 6 and the states are cities aren't lining up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN4jL.png)

I hope I explained this clearly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will always be three items, you can set the `n` arg.

```
undergrad_colleges_supplying_50_med_students.join(
    undergrad_colleges_supplying_50_med_students['undergraduate_institution']
    .str.split(',', n=3, expand=True)
    .fillna(np.nan)
)
```